# API funciona no POSTMAN, mas não no codigo

Tags: javascript, postman, axios

estou tentando acessar uma API, pelo postman, ela funciona e retorna o json normalmente, já pelo codigo (usando VueJS + Axios) não retorna, da erro de CROSS, como isso pode? sendo que o axios retorna normalmente?

```
let headers = {
        'Authorization': 'AUTENTICACAO BASIC',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }

axios.post('URL DA API', body, headers)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
```

No `body`, estou enviando os dados necessarios para o retorno.. Lembando que no postman, retorna o json corretamente.
O retorno é o erro `401`

Comment: Você pode alterar a API para dar acesso a sua aplicação? Se não puder, é possível adicionar um proxy na sua aplicação.

Comment: você pode especificar as urls que podem acessar sua API, usando a annotation @CrossOrigin(url)
com certeza é esse o motivo do erro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É necessário habilitar o CORS no lado na API que você está querendo utilizar.

[HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: habilita o CORS, pode ser via pluggin do chrome ou firefox.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é com o CORS, só consegui resolver o problema dessa forma:

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({origin:true,credentials: true}));
```

E também setando os headers:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, X-Response-Time, X-PINGOTHER, X-CSRF-Token,Authorization');
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
        return res.status(200).end();
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```